# Using sqlalchemy to create an index on a json key (expression index)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The situation is I have a JSON column type in a postgresql table. I'd like to create an index on one or more of the keys in the json. I believe I know how to do this using [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807030/how-to-create-index-on-json-field-in-postgres-9-3) (Side note: I was under the impression that you had to be using jsonb to have this kind of indexing according to the postgresql [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html). Doesn't seem like that's the case.)

For consistency, I'd like to do this through sqlalchemy, but I don't see any mention on how to do this in their docs. Is this possible?

Comment: You want to create an expression index via SQLAlchemy? You'll need to find a way to make it run arbitrary SQL, I really doubt it'll support that natively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've figured out the answer to this question. As Craig pointed out, this is an expression-based index, which was made possible on the JSON column type in [Postgresql 9.3](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.3#JSON:_Additional_functionality).  This can be done through SQLAlchemy in the following manner:

Given a model called `MyModel` and a JSON column type called `data` that takes this form:

```
{"my_key": "my_value"}
```

To create an expression-based index on `my_key`, you could do this:

```
index = Index("my_index_name", MyModel.c.data['my_key'].astext)
index.create(engine)
```

The original answer to this is from Mike Bayer in the SQLAlchemy google group, which you can find [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/3ws_6orlSDY).