# Index JSON Array in Postgres DB

Tags: performance, postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I have a table where each row has a JSON structure as follows that I'm trying to index in a postgresql database and was wondering what the best way to do it is:

```
{
    "name" : "Mr. Jones",
    "wish_list": [
        {"present_name": "Counting Crows",
        "present_link": "www.amazon.com"},
        { "present_name": "Justin Bieber",
        "present_link": "www.amazon.com"},
    ]
}
```

I'd like to put an index on each present_name within the wish_list array. The goal here is that I'd like to be able to find each row where the person wants a particular gift through an index.

I've been reading on how to [create an index on a JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807030/how-to-create-index-on-json-field-in-postgres-9-3) which makes sense. The problem I'm having is creating an index on each element of an array within a JSON object.

The best guess I have is using something like the [json_array_elements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) function and creating an index on each item returned through that.

Thanks for a push in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check [**`JSONB` Indexing**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) section in Postgres documentation.
For your case index config may be the following:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_gin_wishlist ON your_table USING gin ((jsonb_column -> 'wish_list'));
```

It will store copies of every key and value inside `wish_list`, but you should be careful with a query which hits the index. You should use `@>` operator:

```
SELECT jsonb_column->'wish_list'
FROM your_table WHERE jsonb_column->'wish_list' @> '[{"present_link": "www.amazon.com", "present_name": "Counting Crows"}]';
```

**Strongly** suggested to check existing nswers:

- [**How to query for array elements inside JSON type**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22737710/3961156)
- [**Index for finding an element in a JSON array**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405706/3961156)

Comment: if the present link could be anything and the value is not pre-known, i.e, only present_name is known what should the query look like?

Comment: @NischalKumar did you find any answer?

Comment: @Ulvi `SELECT jsonb_column->'wish_list' FROM your_table WHERE wish_list @> '[{"present_name":"Counting Crows"}]' `. In here we can declare wish_list as jsonb column type. I did not look into indexing for this case. Please share your thoughts, how we can index for the same use case.