# Postgres: create index on attribute of attribute in JSONB column?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working in Postgres 9.6.5. I have the following table:

```
 id             | integer      
 data           | jsonb
```

The data in the `data` column is nested, in the form:

```
{ 'identification': { 'registration_number': 'foo' }}
```

I'd like to index `registration_number`, so I can query on it. I've tried this (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807030/how-to-create-index-on-json-field-in-postgres-9-3)):

```
CREATE INDEX ON mytable((data->>'identification'->>'registration_number'));
```

But got this:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text ->> unknown
LINE 1: CREATE INDEX ON psc((data->>'identification'->>'registration...                                                    ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean `data->'identification'->>'registration_number'`. `->` for object, `->>` for text value.

Comment: @teppic yes, that worked, thank you! (if you'd like to submit this as an answer please do)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
CREATE INDEX ON mytable((data -> 'identification' ->> 'registration_number'));
```

The `->` operator returns the `jsonb` object under the key, and the `->>` operator returns the `jsonb` object under the key as `text`. The most notable difference between the two operators is that `->>` will "unwrap" string values (i.e. remove double quotes from the TEXT representation).

The error you're seeing is reported because `data ->> 'identification'` returns `text`, and the subsequent `->>` is not defined for the `text` type.

Answer (score 3):

Since version [9.3 Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) has the `#>` and `#>>` operators. This operators allow the user to specify a path (using an array of text) inside jsonb column to get the value.

You could use this operator to achieve your goal in a simpler way.

```
CREATE INDEX ON mytable((data #>> '{identification, registration_number}'));
```